# Window manager with search feature?

Tags: window-manager, desktop-environment, desktop

If many windows are open, cycling through them can get highly annoying.

**Which window manager has the ability to search through the windows by typing in the title or text inside the application?**

For example: Searching for *“Stac Firef”* will find the StackExchange Firefox window quickly.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `i3wm`'s IPC could be used for scripting a feature like this.  see [i3ipc-python](https://github.com/acrisci/i3ipc-python) and example scripts.

Answer (score 0):

KDE's Krunner will do this. Not technically part of the WM.